# animation with rotateY looks the same in different value

Tags: css

some text from MDN
The amount of rotation created by rotateY() is specified by an . If positive, the movement will be clockwise; if negative, it will be counter-clockwise.

```js
const rotate1 = [
  {
    transform: `rotateX(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateX(0)`
  }
];

const rotate2 = [
  {
    transform: `rotateY(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(-45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(0)`
  }
];

document.getElementById('rotated1').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate1,1000)}
document.getElementById('rotated2').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate2,1000)}

document.getElementById('rotated1').animate(rotate1,1000)
document.getElementById('rotated2').animate(rotate2,1000)
```

```css
div {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}

#rotated1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#rotated2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotated1">click me</div>

<div id="rotated2">click me</div>
```

pls have a look on this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ef3co4hw/)

it makes me confused..

what i expect is : http://img.htmleaf.com/1610/rotateY-demo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some perspective to get what you want:

```js
const rotate1 = [
  {
    transform: `rotateX(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateX(0)`
  }
];

const rotate2 = [
  {
    transform: `rotateY(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(-45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `rotateY(0)`
  }
];

document.getElementById('rotated1').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate1,1000)}
document.getElementById('rotated2').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate2,1000)}

document.getElementById('rotated1').animate(rotate1,1000)
document.getElementById('rotated2').animate(rotate2,1000)
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin:5px;
}

#rotated1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#rotated2 {
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  perspective:200px;
  perspective-origin:left center;
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotated1">click me</div>

<div id="rotated2">click me</div>
```

Or like below:

```js
const rotate1 = [
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateX(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateY(45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateX(0)`
  }
];

const rotate2 = [
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateY(0)`
  },
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateY(-45deg)`
  },
  {
    transform: `perspective(200px) rotateY(0)`
  }
];

document.getElementById('rotated1').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate1,1000)}
document.getElementById('rotated2').onclick = function(){this.animate(rotate2,1000)}

document.getElementById('rotated1').animate(rotate1,1000)
document.getElementById('rotated2').animate(rotate2,1000)
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin:5px;
}

#rotated1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#rotated2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotated1">click me</div>

<div id="rotated2">click me</div>
```

Some related questions for more details:

[perspective and translateZ moves diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54987891/8620333)

[CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51891329/8620333)

Comment: thank you!
I found this awesome site(https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/) which helps me understand what is going on!